# How does symfony's url paser works?

Tags: symfony, routes

Can someone explain it ?
I mean how does symfony knows that this url `/blogs/blog-title` = `/blogs/{title}` 
How does is it parse urls in `routing.yml` and finds out that `blog-title` is the dynamic parameter of the url !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes a few steps indeed. I wrote some example code that just explains it a little bit. **It is not ment to be functional code**.

First thing to is to break the route into snippets:

```
$route = '/blogs/{title}';
$routeArray = explode('/', $route);
```

same thing for the REQUEST_URI that comes with the $_SERVER superglobal:

```
$requestArray = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Now we have to compare the two array's element by element:

```
if(count($routeArray) != count($requestArray)) {
    return FALSE; // the route does not match
}

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($routeArray) ; $i++)
{
     if($routeArray[$i][0] != '{' && $routeArray[$i] != $requestArray[$i]) {
         return FALSE; // the route does not match
     }
}

return TRUE; // still here? route matches!
```

first run of the for loop compares if 'blogs' starts with a '{' or if 'blogs' is the same as 'blogs'.

second run of the for loop  compares if '{title}' starts with a '{' or if '{title}' is the same as 'blog-title'.

besides of this the Symfony router also checks if the REQUEST_METHOD is valid. e.g. GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.

Comment: Thnx it's clear now, exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Slimen I hope My answer will help you:

It is the Router component who does this job.

When you try to access a web page of your application:

Kernel ask to the router component to parse the routing.yml file. So the Router will try to match the current url  with a route defined in routing.yml.

When Router matches a route definition in routing.yml, he will try to look for the parameters of this route (..the controller to execute and the parameters to give to the controller who will be executed (parameters like newsId or userId etc)).

When the Router has parsed the route definition in routing.yml, he will give the collected informations to the kernel.

And now the kernel knows which controller to execute and which paramters to give to that controller.

Comment: Thnx for your answer but I was  asking about the amghorithm. How the Router parse the url and define what is the static side of the url and what is the dynamic side.